# How to identify replacement transformer?

Tags: transformer, repair, replacement

I have a DVD player that is apparently working fine but the power supply makes a loud whining noise. The noise comes from, or from very close to the transformer. Upon close inspection, I see that there is a crack in the frame. The section is still held mostly in place by the wrapping tape but it is possible to shift the outlined section slightly.

I assume the transformer needs to be replaced.

I have the schematics. Additionally, not visible on the picture, the side of the transformer says "TNY267P / HY 0419" (but that appears to refer to the switcher IC). I have another DVD player with a similar PSU, a label of the transformer in that says "P 2472.0001A / 300?9706 / 23105Z / VDE".

How can I identify a compatible replacement transformer?

(Doing this to learn, and to make landfills slightly smaller :) )

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I see that there is a crack in the frame... I assume the transformer needs to be replaced." - why? If the noise bothers you then just glue it back together. The transformer is probably custom made for the device so your chances of finding a generic 'compatible' replacement are slim.

Comment: I assumed that it would not be a reliable fix but. If gluing is fine I'll do that, just need to figure out what kind of glue to use...

Comment: I guess it's a ferrite core. You could replace only the core if it's not potted all in epoxy.

Comment: Can you show said crack? It it justthe parting line between the core halves? Anyhow, I bet 10€ it's dried up capacitors which are the root cause although it's the transformer making the noises.

Comment: @winny I can upload photo later... The parting line is one end of the loose section, the other is a crack near the corner. The entire outlined piece can be shifted up and down slightly (0.1mm or so). About caps - that would make me happy :) I do have replacement caps for the three blue caps on the primary side. If there is a chance any of these causing the transformer noise I'd be happy to try and swap them!

Comment: Frame?  That transformer has a ferrite CORE, is the core cracked?  If so, just dribble in some glue and hope it gets quiet.   It will leak some magnetic field, but there is unlikely to be any issue, the cores are not a  precision component.  Don't lose the piece, though.